# Could flammable alcohol be used as a weapon in combat?

Tags: weapons, fire, alcoholic-beverages

I'm developing a character who becomes stronger the more alcohol is in his body but couldn't think of an appropriate weapon. Then I had the idea that he could use alcohol in some sort of flame based weapon/attack. Could alcohol be used as an effective weapon by boosting a fire attack? Or at the very least would it produce a sizeable amount of fire? Data on flame size using different alcohols as fuel would be helpful. Or what weapons could work well in this way that take advantage of his increase in physical strength or alcohol as a fuel?

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please take our [tour] and read through our [help] to better understand our rules - one of which is that you can ask only one question per post. Have you researched anything? That's desirable here. People start passing out at around 0.2% BAC and die at 0.4%. An adult male has about 1.4 gallons of blood, so you're talking about one tablespoon of alcohol. I don't know what you expect to have happen with that.

Comment: Check the volume of the blood in a normal human body - should be somewhere around 4.5-5l if my memory serve. What percentage of that value you think can substitute with alcohol?

Comment: As a guide for your researches, [engineering toolbox](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/adiabatic-flame-temperature-d_996.html) has some useful info re several organic compounds inc. methanol/ethanol and many others and lots of links to thermodynamic principles etc.

Comment: A really, really large man (250 lb+) that is drunk to the point of falling into a coma from it, has enough alcohol in his blood to fill 2 cups. That's enough firestarter fluid to light *two* barbecue fires, or to start a bonfire but have everyone groan at how lame the startup is. Or to power a typical WWII infantry flamethrower for 1/3 of a second.

Comment: @PcMan in blood? maybe in the body, mainly/specifically the last few cups in the digestive system to be absorbed.

Comment: Sorry new to this and didn't realise there were comments

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I wasn't sure about an exact amount, but basically he would have superhuman tolerance of alcohol and could drink a huge amount. I just tried to do some math about alcohol concentration and how much it would take to get drunk but I failed that haha. It says some guy can have 5 drinks before becoming drunk so I imagine my character (named Arius) would have an amount that wouldn't be unbelievable but ridiculous. Maybe somewhere between 15- 20 equivalent in average beers, but obviously taken in a stronger form as 15-20 beers would be a lot of liquid to consume

Comment: @PcMan Great info thanks! thats really helpful math and I'll definitely consider that when I finalise the characters abilities.

Comment: @Alexander lol would that actually work? I'm actually considering that lol. How much alcohol would you need to intoxicate someone from just breathing in their breath?

Answer (score 4):

Comments under the question address how much alcohol could be in someone's blood.  I'll assume you've handwaved away the limitation that they're unconscious by the time they've accumulated enough to be worth burning.

I've built a [stove that burns alcohol](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/24839/2529).  It's basically the bottom of a drinks can in a windshield.
If I load that up with 10 ml of fuel, several minutes later I'll have a cup of boiling water.  The only major difference between alcohols (denatured ethanol, methanol, and isopropanol) is how visible the flame is/how much soot I get. Even acetone is similar (note it's possible for a human body to produce ketones).  This means you need a lot of fuel to get a big flame.

You would of course do better with a jet than an open cup, but you'd need far more fuel as the jet would need to be ignited at the mouth/nozzle and keep burning to the target.  From doing a little firebreathing years ago,  a mouthful (up to about 100ml) of paraffin/kerosene produces a visually impressive flame but you'd do more damage chucking the fuel can at your target - and have greater range. Perhaps with enough pressure behind it you'd be able to use this to hurt someone at a decent range.  I'd expect alcohols to be less effective; they have  also sometimes been used in firebreathing (but note toxicity in the real world) but produce smaller, less impressive flames.  You may use gauntlets, but this gives an idea of what you can get for biologically relevant quantities and non-ideal nozzles.

An even  bigger problem would be separation of the alcohol from the bloodstream.  You can't filter alcohol out of water with anything short of a reverse osmosis system, and even they're not very good at it while needing lots of power and bulk.  Carrying the fuel already separated would be far more efficient.

On the whole I think you'd be better looking at some sort of berserker

Comment: Thinking about what you said about how you could't seperate the alcohol and the blood, does blood with high (In this case as he is a fictional character, Unrealistically high) alcohol contamination have any unique properties that could be useful in combat? Because if he was a berserker he could punch them hard enough to cause his fists to bleed. I don't know if it would be useful but thought you might have an opinion on it.

Comment: @Mattna if the concentration of alcohol in the blood was high enough to kill a normal person, it might sting a bit of it got in a wound. It's no longer recommended but alcohol (around 70% concentration) has long been used to clean open wounds and is still used on skin (e.g. hand sanitiser). That's enough to burn with a source of ignition, but at that kind of concentration you'd kill the mutant's blood cells so a whole new biochemistry would be needed

Comment: So you would actually be cleaning the wounds you inflict lol

Comment: @Mattna yes, disinfecting them.  I wonder. Now I wonder about  a tolerance to *methanol* that would kill others as it's toxic

Comment: do you mean if my berserker was immune to it? And he could poison others?

Comment: Yes, though the quantity needed would be rather large.  An approach of consuming a poison he's immune to could be better served with something more potent.  Coming back to ethanol (drinking alcohol) I've had a thought that I wonder if you could run with: [Tippler's Bane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinopsis_atramentaria) is a mushroom that's edible but produces a toxin when consumed with alcohol.  That's a long way from where we started though, even if it's interesting

Comment: I do agree thats interesting but I can't really imagine how it would be used as a weapon unless he got enemies to eat it before fighting. Unless he could make himself immune to it but I'm not sure it would be the best option haha

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for this:

1. Poisonous bite, where alcohol is the venom. The venom is stored in a specialised organ in the body and is released upon biting. Injecting a large volume of ethanol into the bloodstream of the victim would weaken the victim's ability to fight back. Moreover, perhaps ethanol is converted to methanol in the venom gland, making deadlier in relatively low concentrations.
2. Resistance to a pathogen. The character has grenade-like packages that can be thrown at people. When a package breaks, it releases a puff of dust that contains deadly bacteria. The bacteria can normally infect anyone quickly but high blood alcohol content wards these bacteria off.

Answer (score 0):

/On the whole I think you'd be better looking at some sort of berserker  @Chris H/

Oh yeah.

1. He is stronger when he drinks alcohol.  In large part because he is less careful but he is also stronger because he is singing his fighting song.
2. His weapon is whatever is handy.  It is never the same thing twice because that thing is usually not fit to be used as a weapon the second time.
3. His drink of choice is 160 proof moonshine with some herbs in it.  He strips off his clothes, pours some on himself and lights himself on fire.  He is a very hairy dude which helps hold the alcohol.  He is also very sweaty which helps him not get burned.  He will only burn for a while unless it has been a while since he did this, in which case his hair will burn longer because it is longer.  The burning hair makes a lot of smoke.
4. His main attack is wrestling which he uses after he breaks whatever he was using as a weapon.  I learned in junior high "never fight a wrestler, because they won't fight. They will wrestle.  And they know how to hurt you."  Your flaming naked man will close with opponents and grapple them.  He is loud when he does this because he is singing, like he was before he did it.

The flames are not that hot and unless you catch fire yourself they will probably not damage you any more than you already get damaged.  And you will probably not catch fire because you have wet yourself because this dude is terrifying.

Comment: I like your idea of the crazy berserker type, I just have one question about the hair. The way you explained the hair burning suggests to me that he could only use this fire ability after his hair regrows. If this makes sense, how long would he have to wait for his hair to regrow? And how long could it burn for?

Comment: If you pour alcohol on bare skin, or a baked alaska, it will burn off.  For skin it is a party trick.  If you have a lot of greasy hair maybe it will catch on fire and keep burning.  I am sure a lot of matted body hair would burn longer than clean shaven skin.  I think if you assert it one way or the other in your story readers will roll with it.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense I'll have a think about it